# Intellij Plugin to generate an android project nature

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-plugin

Is it possible to implement an Intellij plugin that can generate a personalized android project in my workspace ? 
I'm looking for a source code of such plugin 
Best Regards

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to implement such a plugin, but I'm not aware of the existence of any such plugins.

Comment: I found many plugins examples that can create a project in a workspace, I know it's possible like I did already with eclipse, but I can't figure out how to do it